Issue loading profile page console render empty user id to identify profiledata
Hello I have a react component that generates a url for each user after its username is create. I added a profiledata function that fetches the data from the database to the right user profile however when I'm logged out i can't get access to the Profiledata of specific user like i should be, its stuck in this loop.
if (!profileData) { return <div>Loading...</div>;  status }
I tried very hard to fix the problem but it seems to me that it comes from here
const checkIfOwnProfile = async () => { const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser(); if (user) { setIsOwnProfile(user.id === profileOwnerId); // User is logged in, check if it's their profile } else { setIsOwnProfile(false); // If no user is logged in, set isOwnProfile to false } };
because when trying to access the page logged out, I get in the console that user_id is null and therefore profiledata is not displaying. I dont know why it compares my user_id from a state of authenticated or not, I want people to be able to access Profiledata regardless of being authenticated or not, can anybody help me figure out a logical way to do that.the only place where only the relevant user has access to should be the child component settings. the full component down bellow
import supabase from '../../../utils/supabase';

const ProfileDashboard = ({ profileOwnerId }: { profileOwnerId: string }) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('Overview');
  const [isOwnProfile, setIsOwnProfile] = useState(false); // Only for the Settings tab
  const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState<any>(null); // Stores profile data

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProfileData = async () => {
      // Fetch profile details without checking user auth status
      const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('profiles')
        .select('username, dob, height, weight, fat, about, last_seen, role, created_at')
        .eq('id', profileOwnerId)
        .single();

      if (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching profile data:', error.message);
      } else {
        setProfileData(data);
      }
    };

 const checkIfOwnProfile = async () => {
  const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
  if (user) {
    setIsOwnProfile(user.id === profileOwnerId); // User is logged in, check if it's their profile
  } else {
    setIsOwnProfile(false); // If no user is logged in, set isOwnProfile to false
  }
};

    fetchProfileData();       // Fetch profile data regardless of authentication
    checkIfOwnProfile();      // Check if the viewer is the profile owner
  }, [profileOwnerId]);

  if (!profileData) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;  // This will only wait on profile data, not ownership status
  }

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <header id="header-container" />
      <div className="bg-bg11">
        <div className="tab-list w-80 mx-auto d-flex align-items-center gap-4">
          <a 
            href="#"
            className={`tab-trigger fs-6 py-1-5 ${activeTab === 'Overview' ? 'active' : ''}`}
            onClick={() => setActiveTab('Overview')}
          >
            Overview
          </a>
          {isOwnProfile && (
            <a 
              href="#"
              className={`tab-trigger fs-6 py-1-5 ${activeTab === 'Settings' ? 'active' : ''}`}
              onClick={() => setActiveTab('Settings')}
            >
              Settings
            </a>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="main-wrapper mx-auto mt-3">
        <div className="main-section user-dashboard mt-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
          <section className="profile-card bg-bg11">
            <span className="color-bg bg-black"></span>
            <div className="profile-card_header d-flex flex-column align-items-center gap-2">
              <img src="/images/profile-pic.png" alt="Profile" />
              <span className="visibility-status online d-flex align-items-center gap-2">
                <span className="dot"></span><span>Online</span>
              </span>
              <h5 className="username">{profileData.username}</h5>
              <p className="about fs-8">{profileData.about}</p>
              <div className="tab w-100 mt-3">
                <div className="tab-list d-flex align-items-center gap-3">
                  <a href="#" className="tab-trigger active fs-9 py-0">Info</a>
                  <a href="#" className="tab-trigger fs-9 py-0">Stats</a>
                  <a href="#" className="tab-trigger fs-9 py-0">Karma</a>
                </div>
                <div className="tab-content" id="info">
                  <p><span className="fw-bold">Role :</span> <span>{profileData.role}</span></p>
                  <p><span className="fw-bold">Last seen :</span> <span>{profileData.last_seen}</span></p>
                  <p><span className="fw-bold">Since :</span> <span>{profileData.created_at}</span></p>
                  <p><span className="fw-bold">Born :</span> <span>{profileData.dob}</span></p>
                  <p><span className="fw-bold">Weight :</span> <span>{profileData.weight}</span></p>
                  <p><span className="fw-bold">Height :</span> <span>{profileData.height}</span></p>
                  <p><span className="fw-bold">Body Fat :</span> <span>{profileData.fat}%</span></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>

          {/* Conditionally render TabContents or ProfileSettings */}
          {activeTab === 'Overview' ? <TabContents /> : isOwnProfile && <ProfileSettings />}
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfileDashboard;


Can you edit your question, with better and neat description?
currently it looks quite confusing, I didn't understand what exactly you are looking for.
